# Switch Apache from worker MPM back to prefork

Tags: apache-httpd, php

I have an installed version of Apache 2.4 and I am trying to install PHP7, following the [instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php). However, I have hit a snag:

```
Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe. You need to recompile PHP.
```

I do not want to use a multithreaded version of PHP (directly discouraged). I don't have a `modules/mod_mpm_event.so` library, so cannot follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248003/httpd-wont-start-with-added-lines-for-php). So how can I [configure Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248003/httpd-wont-start-with-added-lines-for-php) without recompiling?

Comment: Use MPM prefork, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html.  If you have it...  Is this a self hosted Apache or something from a provider?

Comment: Self-hosted. I'm aware I need to use `prefork`, but it is not clear how I change from `worker` to `prefork` short of recompiling.

Comment: Check this link, answer by Chris Johnson is the way to go for this: https://serverfault.com/questions/88000/how-do-i-tell-if-apache-is-running-as-prefork-or-worker/488402

Comment: Actually, it was JorgeeFG's answer which helped. Turns out it's a Ubuntu specific question. The `.load` file also indicates where the `.so` library is (in my case, `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/`.

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate question. Although the answer is. And it's also Ubuntu specific. Can this question be filed somewhere or should it just be marked as duplicate? Should I leave an answer regardless?